# For Loops in R for modelling

Tags: r

I am trying to run a rpart, Tree model in which my HW problem states that I have to iterate the model for different values of cp. I want to make a for loop for the same. 
Eg. cp ranges from 0.01 to 0.10, I want to make a loop/or use apply family functions to get 10 models named tree_mod1, tree_mod2 and so on. 
Can someone pls help me how to go about it? I am farely new in R, and I cannot find the answer I am looking for online. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of cp values and use lapply to iterate over this:

```
cp <- list(cp1 = the_first_cp, 
           cp2 = the_second_cp)
model_list <- lapply(cp, function(x) rpart(rpart arguments, cp = x))
names(model_list) <- names(cp)
```

`x` corresponds to the value of `cp` in a particular iteration. This will create a list of models for each of you `cp` value.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the solution! this helps. I also need to save each of these models with different names. Any idea how I can do that??

Comment: If your original list of cps are named, you can use the same (or modified) names for your list of models. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to [haci's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038648/10782538) good and complete answer, your chances for getting a good answer on goes way up, if you include a snippet of code of what you have tried yourself.

In this case there's quite a lot of packages to create tree based models. `rpart` is usually one of the faster ones, but we don't know which one you have been asked to use.

Obviously you could do this manually

```
library(rpart)
data(kyphosis, package = "rpart")
tree_mods <- list()
form <- Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start
tree_mods[["treemod1"]] <- rpart(form, data = kyphosis, cp = 0.01)
tree_mods[["treemod1"]] <- rpart(form, data = kyphosis, cp = 0.02)
...
```

being new in `R` this could lead to the conclusion of a `loop` over the `cp` argument. On [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r%2Bloops?tab=Newest) there is currently [5397 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r%2Bloops?tab=Newest) with the tags `R` and `loops`. An answer is nested somewhere within those.

Saving you the trouble, I'll give an example of how one can use a `for loop` here, while [haci's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038648/10782538) answer contains an example of `lapply`. For loops are slightly faster but often less readable.

```
(cp <- seq(0.01, 0.1, by = 0.01))
#[1] 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10
tree_list <- list() #or better: tree_list <- vector("list", 10)
for(i in 1:10)
    tree_list[[i]] <- cp[i] * 3
names(tree_list) <- paste0("treemod", 1:10, sep = "")
```

As it is a homework assignment you should be able to change the loop to your needs as part of the assignment.

## Edit: Time difference of apply and for loop

From the comments the question whether it isnt `*apply`'s that are faster than `for loops` in R. It is a common myth, which was the case prior to an update some years ago that improved `for loops` performance in R. Below I've added a small illustration calculating column means. (Note. Don't do what i do in the example. Use `colMeans` instead. It is just for illustration)

```
n <- 100
ncols <- 1000
dat <- matrix(rnorm(n * ncols), ncol = ncols)
meth1 <- function(x){
    output <- numeric(n <- ncol(x))
    for(i in seq(n))
        output[i] <- mean(x[,1])
}
meth2 <- function(x)
    apply(x, 2, mean)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(`for loop` = meth1(dat), `apply` = meth2(dat))
#output
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 for loop 6.343370 6.585399 7.204251 6.793824 7.061341 22.28108   100
    apply 7.346981 7.548421 8.269624 7.758734 8.109884 23.40703   100
```

From the output we can see that both the minimum, mean and median time is lower the the `for loop` over 100 repetitions. The reason is that regardless of the method, you'll have to `loop` over whatever you're doing when programming. The `*apply` functions basically creates the loop for you, but it is still there. A bit of overhead is added due to the general implementation of the `*apply` functions, which takes any input and possibly formats the output. The larger the loop however the smaller the difference will be, and thus they are often used to make code more readable. The goal of your R-code should always be to make it readable over making it fast. Other languages are better for speed (`C`, `C++`, `C#`, `F`, low-level `Julia` etc.) But if your code doesn't gain readability from using `*apply`, maybe just stick to the for loop in that case.

Comment: Regarding "For loops are slightly faster but often less readable", isn't it the other way around?

Comment: It used to be, and if one searches the internet the top hits are often references that will tell this as de facto. It is however not the case. An update (believe back in 2015 or further back) changed the `for loops` in R, and they were vastly improved. Basically `apply` will create a `for loop` internally and run the function for you (not exactly but close enough). The time it requires to create the `for loop` is overhead, and this will make it a bit slower. Additional formatting is done at the end, adding a bit more overhead. The longer the loop the smaller the difference.

Comment: I've added a small example (in a moment) to the answer, illsutrating the time difference for a small example.